# Image sizing/scaling issues

Tags: html, css

Ok, so im creating a portfolio for myself, and im just about done with the exception of my images. Which unfortunately if not fixed ruins the ENTIRE design. I have one images that is WAY TOO BIG all throughout each size, and I have 3 images that are sized properly for desktop but when entered into a mobile view, the images become way too large!

[Image way too large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zllyu.png)

As you can see in the photo above, this image, even in desktop view, is WAY TOO LARGE. So large in fact that it is giving me the option to scroll from left to right just to view the entire photo. Which of course ruins almost every other part of the web design.

In the image below, you can see what it's SUPPOSED to look like. Images are scaled to a reasonable level. Although these images are scaled properly for desktop, They are not scaling to mobile view properly. At about 800px they are ok, but once they enter the screen size of a phone, they become WAY TOO LARGE.

[Scaled properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUCLD.png)

With the images properly scaled for mobile, the text and photo should stack on top of one another.

[Images too large for mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIfB5.png)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

image {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-container {
  background: #6700ee;

  a{
    color: white;
  }
}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2em;

  .logo {
    color: #00f7ff;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  ul {
    display: flex;

    a {
      display: block;
      padding: 0 1em;
    }
  }
}

.social-header, .hero-design {
    display: none;
}

.hero {
    background: #6e00ff;
    color: white;
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4em;
}

.meet {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff64cb;

    span {
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-right: .5em;
    }
}

.scroll {
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

section {
    padding: 4em 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.featured {
    position: relative;
}
.featured::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #e5d5fa;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.subtitle {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6e00ff;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-size: .85em;
}

.featured-title {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-top: -.4em;
    display: block;
}

.featured-desc {
    color: #252525;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.skills {
    background: #ff64cb;
}

.skills-container ul li {
    background: white;
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;

    .icon-container {
        height: 100px;
        display: grid;
        place-content: center;
        margin: 0 auto;

        &.one {
            width: 50px;
        }
        &.two {
            width: 100px;
        }
        &.three {
            width: 60px;
        }
    } 
    .skill-title {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .featured-desc {
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
}

.portfolio {
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

.portfolio-container a img {
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .featured, .portfolio {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .featured, .portfolio-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 40% auto;
    }
    .left, .portfolio-left {
        display: grid;
        place-content: center;

    }
    .right {
        margin-left: 2em;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }

    .skills {
        margin-top: -5em;
        margin-bottom: -7em;
        padding-top: 7em;
    }

    .skills-container ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
        grid-gap: 1em;
    }

    .portfolio {
        padding-top: 7em;
    }
    .portfolio-container img {
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
    .hero {
        height: 90vh;
    }

    .nav-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 66% auto;
        background: unset;

        header {
            background: #6700ee;
        }
    }
    header {
        padding: 2em 2em 2em 4em;
    }
    .social-header {
        padding: 2em 4em 2em 0;
    }
    section {
        padding: 4em;
    }

    .social-header {
        display: block;
        ul {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            width: 7em;
            float: right;

            img {
                width: 20px;
            }
        }
    }

    .hero {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 66% auto;
        background: unset;
        padding: 0;

        .content {
            background: #6e00ff;
            padding: 6em 8em 6em 4em;
            text-align: left;

            h1 {
                font-size: 3em;
                line-height: 1.2em;
            }
        }
    }
    .meet {
        margin: unset;
    }
    .hero-design {
        display: unset;
        margin-left: -50%;
        margin-top: 15%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .portfolio img {
        float: right;
        max-width: 500px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1250px) {
    header {
        padding: 2em 2em 2em 10em;
    }
    .social-header {
        padding: 2em 10em 2em 0;
    }
    section {
        padding: 10em 10em 4em 10em;
    }
    .hero .content {
        padding: 6em 8em 6em 10em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1550px) {
    header {
        padding: 2em 2em 2em 20em;
    }
    .social-header {
        padding: 2em 20em 2em 0;
    }
    section {
        padding: 20em 10em 4em 20em;
    }
    .hero .content {
        padding: 6em 8em 6em 20em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <header>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">Isaiah Johnson</a>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">My Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="">My Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Hire Me</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <div class="social-header">
        <!-- MAKE SURE IMAGES ARE VISIBLE -->
        <ul>
          <li><a href=""><img src="images/dribble.png" alt="dribble"/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="images/github.png" alt="github"/></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"/></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>YOUR FAVORITE WEB DESIGNER<br /> YOU HAVENT HIRED <br />YET</h1>
        <div class="meet">
          <span></span>
          <p>Meet Isaiah Johnson</p>
        </div>
        <svg class="scroll" width="36" height="76" viewBox="0 0 36 76">
          <g id="scroll" transform="translate(-186 -482)">
            <g id="Rectangle_3" data-name="Rectangle 3" transform="translate(186 482)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="6">
              <path d="M17.333,0H18A18,18,0,0,1,36,18V58A18,18,0,0,1,18,76h0A18,18,0,0,1,0,58V17.333A17.333,17.333,0,0,1,17.333,0Z" stroke="none"/>
              <path d="M17.375,3H18A15,15,0,0,1,33,18V58A15,15,0,0,1,18,73h0A15,15,0,0,1,3,58V17.375A14.375,14.375,0,0,1,17.375,3Z" fill="none"/>
            </g>
            <g id="Rectangle_4" data-name="Rectangle 4" transform="translate(197 494)" fill="#fff" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1">
              <rect width="15" height="17" rx="7.5" stroke="none"/>
              <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="14" height="16" rx="7" fill="none"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="hero-design" width="520" height="520" viewBox="0 0 520 520">
        <g id="hero-image" transform="translate(-1006 -161)">
          <rect class="square-anim" id="Rectangle_5" data-name="Rectangle 5" width="130" height="130" rx="19" transform="translate(1266 161)" fill="#6e00ff"/>
          <rect class="square-anim" id="Rectangle_10" data-name="Rectangle 10" width="130" height="130" rx="19" transform="translate(1266 421)" fill="#6e00ff"/>
          <rect class="square-anim" id="Rectangle_7" data-name="Rectangle 7" width="130" height="130" rx="19" transform="translate(1396 291)" fill="#6e00ff" opacity="0.39"/>
          <rect class="square-anim" id="Rectangle_6" data-name="Rectangle 6" width="130" height="130" rx="19" transform="translate(1136 291)" fill="#fff"/>
          <rect class="square-anim" id="Rectangle_9" data-name="Rectangle 9" width="130" height="130" rx="19" transform="translate(1136 551)" fill="#fff"/>
          <rect class="square-anim" id="Rectangle_8" data-name="Rectangle 8" width="130" height="130" rx="19" transform="translate(1006 421)" fill="#fff" opacity="0.27"/>
          <circle class="square-anim" id="Ellipse_1" data-name="Ellipse 1" cx="64.5" cy="64.5" r="64.5" transform="translate(1266 291)" fill="#ff64cb"/>
          <circle class="square-anim" id="Ellipse_2" data-name="Ellipse 2" cx="64.5" cy="64.5" r="64.5" transform="translate(1136 422)" fill="#00f7ff"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <!-- FEATURED PROJECT -->
    <section class="featured">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="inner transition2">
          <p class="subtitle">Featured Project</p>
          <a href="" class="featured-title">DesignCourse.com ReDesign</a>
          <p class="featured-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In vel necessitatibus illum cupiditate consequatur ratione.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img class="right transition2" src="images/designcourse.jpg" alt="Seductivebox">
    </section>

<!-- SKILLS SECTION-->
  <!-- UX DESIGN -->
    <section class="skills">
      <div class="skills-container">
        <ul>
          <li class="transition2">
            <div class="icon-container one">
              <img src="images/pointer.png" alt="UI/UX Icon">
            </div>
            <p class="skill-title">UI UX Design</p>
            <p class="featured-desc skill-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In vel necessitatibus illum cupiditate consequatur ratione.</p>
          </li>
  <!-- FRONTEND DEVELOPMENT -->
          <li class="transition2">
            <div class="icon-container two">
              <img src="images/frontend.svg" alt="frontend">
            </div>
            <p class="skill-title">Frontend Development</p>
            <p class="featured-desc skill-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In vel necessitatibus illum cupiditate consequatur ratione.</p>
          </li>
  <!-- IDENTITY DESIGN -->
          <li class="transition2">
            <div class="icon-container three">
              <img src="images/identity.svg" alt="identity">
            </div>
            <p class="skill-title">Identity Design</p>
            <p class="featured-desc skill-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In vel necessitatibus illum cupiditate consequatur ratione.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </section>


<!-- PORTFOLIO SECTION -->
  <!-- FIRST PROJECT -->
    <section class="portfolio">
      <div class="portfolio-container transition3">
        <div class="portfolio-left">
          <div class="inner">
            <p class="subtitle">Lingerie Subscription Box</p>
            <p class="featured-title">Seductivebox</p>
            <p class="featured-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, nam!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href=""><img src="images/seductivebox.jpg" alt="seductivebox"> </a>
      </div>

  <!-- SECOND PROJECT   -->
      <div class="portfolio-container transition3">
        <div class="portfolio-left">
          <div class="inner">
            <p class="subtitle">Dog Dating App</p>
            <p class="featured-title">Tindog</p>
            <p class="featured-desc">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui, velit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href=""><img src="images/seductivebox.jpg" alt="seductivebox"> </a>
      </div>

  <!-- THIRD PROJECT -->
      <div class="portfolio-container transition3">
        <div class="portfolio-left">
          <div class="inner">
            <p class="subtitle">Vanilla Coding</p>
            <p class="featured-title">Virtual Keyboard</p>
            <p class="featured-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, soluta!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href=""><img src="images/seductivebox.jpg" alt="seductivebox"> </a>
      </div>

    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `img { width: 100%; }` to your CSS and see if it helps.

Comment: That fixed it. When I was reading your comment, I was like "I have that though...." After review I had Image spelled out instead of img. Coding is so tedious. Thank you for your help!